# R: can inner function use the variables of an outer function?

Tags: r, precision

Can a inner function use the variables that exist in the environment of the function calling it?

```
inner <- function(x)
{
    return(x*y*z*a)
}
outer <- function(x,y,z)
{

    a <- x*y*z
    inner(x)
}
```

Here, when I call `inner(x)`, does it have access to `a, y` and `z`?

Comment: You can specify the `envir` for the function `inner` to lookup on i.e. `parent.frame`

Comment: Did you try calling `outer` to see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

**1)**  If we define `inner` within the definition of `outer` then it will have access to the variables in `outer`.

```
outer <- function(x,y,z) {
    inner <- function(x) x*y*z*a
    a <- x*y*z
    inner(x)
}
outer(2, 3, 4)
## [1] [1] 576
```

**2)** We can copy inner resetting its environment to the environment within the current running instance of `outer`.  This requires that we modify `outer` but not `inner`.

```
inner <- function(x) x*y*z*a

outer <- function(x,y,z) {
    environment(inner) <- environment() # makes temp copy of inner
    a <- x*y*z
    inner(x)
}
outer(2, 3, 4)
## [1] [1] 576
```

**3)** We can change inner to use the variables from its caller.  This requires that we modify `inner` but not `outer`.

```
inner <- function(x) eval.parent(substitute(x*y*z*a))

outer <- function(x,y,z) {
    a <- x*y*z
    inner(x)
}
outer(2, 3, 4)
## [1] [1] 576
```

Comment: But would you actually recommend these strategies? I would probably suggest to users to make proper functions that take the parameters they need as explicit inputs rather than manipulating environments.

Comment: Such a suggestion may be impractical. (1) does not manipulate environments and is widely used and recommended way to use R.  (2)  avoids rewriting `inner`  Such rewriting may be impractical if the author did not write `inner`.  (3) avoids rewriting `outer`.  Such rewriting may be impractical if the user did not write `outer`.  This third approach is used with tcl/tk GUIs, e.g. R Commander, where the main package-free alternative is to use global variables which seems worse. Regarding passing all variables as arguments that may also be impractical if you have a large number of them.